# Do not get result for all sqlite pragmas via QSqlQuery

Tags: linux, windows, qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

I want to get the current states of sqlite pragma using Qt's QSqlQuery.
But I do not get a result for some values from the program but from sqlite console.
Qt version 5.2.1, Sqlite version 3.8.4.3, Windows 7, Ubuntu 12.4 LTS

Output:
    application_id = "0"
    auto_vacuum = "0"
    automatic_index = "1"
    busy_timeout = "5000"
    cache_size = "2000"
    cache_spill = **[NoResult]**
    case_sensitive_like = **[NoResult]**

```
void MySqliteInfo::PrintState(QString state)
{
    printf("%s = ", state.toStdString().c_str());
    QSqlQuery query(*m_db);
    query.prepare(QString("PRAGMA %1").arg(state));
    query.exec();

    if(0 == query.size()) {
        printf("%s returns nothing\n", state.toStdString().c_str());
    }
    else {
        if(query.next()) {
            QVariant value = query.value(0);
            if(value.canConvert(QMetaType::QString)) {
                printf("\"%s\"\n", value.toString().toStdString().c_str());
            }
            else {
                printf("[UnknownDataType]\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("[NoResult]\n");
        }
    }
    query.finish();
}

PrintState("application_id");
PrintState("auto_vacuum");
PrintState("automatic_index");
PrintState("busy_timeout");
PrintState("cache_size");
PrintState("cache_spill");
PrintState("case_sensitive_like");
```

Comment: What is the resulit of `SELECT sqlite_version()`?

Comment: sqlite> select sqlite_version();  ---> 
    3.8.4.3

Comment: In Qt, not in the shell.

Comment: Qt brings Version = 3.7.17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLite version that you are actually using in your Qt program does not yet implement `PRAGMA cache_spill`.

SQLite just ignores any PRAGMA it does not recognize.

As [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_case_sensitive_like), `PRAGMA case_sensitive_like` does not allow reading the current value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `query.size()` test ist useless, since it returns `-1` for every value. `query.size()` can only be used with `SELECT` queries.

Now `[NoResult]` can have two different meanings:

1. A pragma value does not exist
2. A pragma value is `Not Set`

In an example database created from another program, I observe the first case for `cache_spill` and the second case for `case_sensitive_like`. You might want to check the values using [sqliteman on Ubuntu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/sqliteman/).

Comment: @Th.Thielemann This setting applies only to the current connection, not to the database file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution tt least for cache_spill:
The used sqlite3.exe supports pragma cache_spill but not the sqlite version comes with Qt 5.2. (3.7.17).
Qt 5.3 comes with Sqlite 3.8.4.3 - the git repro says this.